# Como limpar um @Html.TextboxFor usando JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

estou tentando limpar o valor inserido no campo do `TextBoxFor` do seguinte formulário logo após o submit.

```
@BHS_Treinamento.WebApi.Models.Curso

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Cadastrar";
}

<h1>Cadastrar</h1>

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { @action = "/api/cursos/", onsubmit = "return submitForm()"})) {
<!--Abaixo o Ajax BeginForm-->
@*@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Cadastrar", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "submitForm" })) {*@
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)


<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome)
</div>
<div class="editor-field" >
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nome, new { id = "modelNome" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome)
</div>
<br />
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success"/>
</p>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Voltar para Home", "Index", "Home")
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function submitForm() {
    debugger;
    if ($("#modelNome").val().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "").length != 0) {
        alert("Cadastrado com sucesso: " + $("#modelNome").val());
    }
    else
        alert("Erro, campo não pode ficar vazio.");
    //$("#modelNome").val("");
}
</script>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Desse jeito o valor valor é inserido ok. Se eu tiro o comentário do script pro campo **nome** receber **vazio** (`$("#modelNome").val("");`) o valor é inserido como vazio também, porque a ação do form é `onSubmit`, ou seja, antes de salvar, o valor é alterado e é passado esse novo valor para o cadastro.
Olhei em outros fóruns que algumas pessoas utilizam o **@Ajax.BeginForm** para poder usar o `OnSuccssess`,(esta comentado como tentei utilizar), porém ele não salva o dado mas limpa a tela. Então decidi olhar no **debugger** pelo navegador e vi que ele não entra na função **submitForm** criada.
Estou começando agora na programação então agradeço a compreensão se o nivel da pergunta for abaixo da média.

Comment: Vou dar um tiro no escuro, mas tente isso no AjaxOptions: `{ OnSuccess = "function(){submitForm(); }" }`

Comment: @Phiter deu certo não, tinha tentado algo parecido tbm que não deu certo, mas obrigado a participação

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para utilizar o método `Ajax.BeginForm()` é necessário que o plugin  `Microsof jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax` seja referenciado no seu projeto/arquivo (disponível no *NuGet*).

Com o plugin referenciado e a rota configurada corretamente, as operações realizadas poderão ser acompanhadas na aba `Network` na *Ferramentas do Desenvolvedor* do seu navegador.

Observe que na propriedade `OnSuccess` da classe `AjaxOptions` deve ser atribuída a função *javascript* que será responsável por realizar a ação posterior ao cadastro que foi realizado com sucesso.

Comment: mto obrigado, deu certo aqui e agora esta chamando a função certinho só que agora não esta passando o valor pra salvar, deve ser algum erro na sintaxe  no meu `Ajax.BeginForm`, vou pesquisar aqui, mto obrigado.

Comment: de fato era um erro na minha sintaxe, tava passando o `Controller` errado e não estava passando a rota, agora esta funcionando perfeitamente, vlw.